# OrmLite is not recognizing Unicode in JSON field

Tags: mysql, .net, c#-4.0, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Ormlite doesn't seem to recognize unicode strings (Arabic) that are stored inside the new 'json' field in MySql. I'm using MySql 5.7 engine .. Arabic is working for all other fields .. stored correctly and retrieved correctly by OrmLite .. The problem is only with arabic inside Json field .. Although, it gets stored correctly by OrmLite but when retrieving them (as a string field in a POCO class), english characters in the JSON field will look correct but all arabic letters will appear as strange encoded characters like this :

{"pn_apns": null, "SenderId": "4744", "pn_debug": false, "MessageText": "Ø§Ù„Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø¹Ù„ÙŠÙƒÙ… Ø¯ÙƒØªÙˆØ± ØŒ Ø§Ù†Ø§ Ø­Ø§Ø¨Ù‡ Ø§Ø³Ø£Ù„Ùƒ Ù„Ùˆ Ø¹Ù†Ø¯Ùƒ Ø®Ø¨Ø±Ù‡ Ù„Ø§Ù† Ø³Ø£Ù„Øª Ø¯ÙƒØªÙˆØ± Ø¹ÙŠÙˆÙ† ÙˆÙ…Ø§Ø±Ø¯ Ø¹Ù„ÙŠØ§ ØŒ Ø¹ÙŠÙ†ÙŠ Ø§Ù„ÙŠØ³Ø§Ø± Ù„Ù‡Ø§ ÙØªØ±Ù‡ ØªØ±Ù . Ø¨Ø³ Ù…Ùˆ Ù…ØªÙˆØ§ØµÙ„ ØªØ±ÙˆØ­ Ù„Ø«ÙˆØ§Ù†ÙŠ ÙˆØªØ±Ø¬Ø¹ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÙŠ ØŒ ÙˆØ§Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ… Ù‚Ù…Øª Ù„Ù‚ÙŠØª Ø¹ÙŠÙ†ÙŠ Ù…Ù†ÙÙˆØ®Ù‡ Ø´ÙˆÙŠÙŠØ§ Ø§Ù„Ø¬ÙÙ† Ù†Ø§Ø²Ù„ ÙŠØ¹Ù†ÙŠ ÙƒØ§Ù†Ù‡Ø§ Ù…Ø·Ø¨Ù‚Ù‡ . Ø§ÙŠØ´ Ø§Ù„Ø­Ù„ ØŸ Ø³ÙˆÙŠØª ÙƒÙ…Ø§Ø¯Ø§Øª Ø´Ø§Ù‡ÙŠ ÙˆØ³ÙˆÙŠØª ÙƒÙ…Ø§Ø¯Ø§Øª Ø¨Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ù‡ . ØªØ®ÙˆÙ ÙˆÙ„Ø§Ø¹Ø§Ø¯ÙŠ ØŸØŸ ", "CreationDate": "2016-12-02T10:10:19.717Z", "ChatMessageId": 0, "ChatMessageType": 1, "DeliveryTimeToken": 0, "SenderDisplayName": "Hanan Ahmed1", "MediaHasBeenfetched": false, "ShowTypingIndicator": false}

I tried settings the following but no luck :

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = MySqlDialect.Provider;
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter().UseUnicode = true;
```

Is there any workaround to solve this or am I missing something ?

Comment: This issue is likely due to MySql's ADO.NET provider having different behavior for reading a string from a JSON column. This may potentially be resolved by registering a [custom Type Converter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/OrmLite-Type-Converters) that inherits from [MySqlStringConverter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql/Converters/MySqlStringConverters.cs). In the meantime can you update your question to include a stand-alone failing test case.